# Gulp serve error events.js: 85

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gulp, gulp-less

I am getting error while doing gulp serve. I am pretty new to all this npm, bower and gulp/grunt stuff. So I was wondering what could be the possible reason for this error. Has anyone experienced this error before? I have attached the following screen-shot.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: That "Unhandled error event" message just means that an error has been emitted from a stream and was not handled. Looks like your gulp-less stream emitted the error, check your Less files' syntax.

Comment: It seems alright. I have one app.less which has syntax as "@import('styles/base.less') and in base.less there is none. By the way I have other fontawesome less files.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses: `@import "styles/base.less";`, you may also want to try to compile the Less files using a different tool to check if they compile correctly.

Comment: Is ther any tool that you know of to compile less files?

Comment: There's the [command line](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage), and depending on your OS, there are GUIs such as WinLess, SimpLESS.

Comment: Thanks @FabrícioMatté! It happens to be the twitter bs and fontawesome files that I installed with bower. Some how if I remove those from the app then gulp process finely. If I have any of those files, then throws that error.  This is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after digging deeper into this issue, I finally found the solution. It was the issue with gulp-less. What I did was bower uninstall gulp-less and then again did bower install gulp-less. It solved my problem. Also had to downgrade fontawesome to 4.2.0. I hope it helps other people out there. Cheers!